# Angular 6: navigating between modules not working

Tags: angular, typescript, module, routes

I'm developing a training app where there is a CourseModule that lazy loads.

```
// from app.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'curso',
  canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
  data: { preload: true },
  loadChildren: './course/course.module#CourseModule'
}, ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

Then in the CourseModule some of the routing points to components while other paths point to load on-demand modules.

```
// from CourseModule
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':stateID/:modID',
    component: CourseComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'video/:id',
        component: VideoPlayerShellComponent,
        data: { domain: videoDomain, animation: 'video' },
        resolve: { urlData: UrlIdResolver }
      },
      { path: 'ig/:id',
        component: InfoGadgetShellComponent,
        data: { domain: videoDomain, animation: 'ig' },
        resolve: { urlData: UrlIdResolver }
      },
      {
        path: 'checar-la-id',
        data: { preload: false, animation: 'id-check' },
        resolve: { urlData: UrlIdResolver },
        loadChildren: './activity-modules/id-check/id-check.module#IdCheckModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'concurso-para-genios',
        data: { preload: false, animation: 'whiz-quiz' },
        resolve: { urlData: UrlIdResolver },
        loadChildren: './activity-modules/whiz-quiz/whiz-quiz.module#WhizQuizModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

The on-demand modules routing are simple like so...

```
// from WhizQuizModule
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: WhizQuizComponent, data: { title: 'Concurso para Genios' } }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

The problem is when I navigate from a module to a module (ie: 'checar-la-id' to 'concurso-para-genios'), the component from the module I am leaving stays on screen and the component from the module I am navigating to never loads. I have no problem navigating between a component that is part of the CourseModule to one of the on-demand loaded modules (ie: 'video/:id' to 'checar-la-id'). That all seems to work fine.

Am I missing something in how I am defining my routes?

Router-Outlet HTML:

```
// from app.component
<div class="content-wrap">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

// from course.component (same result when fadeAnimation is disabled)
<div #lesson class="lesson" [@fadeAnimation]="getRouteAnimation(route)">
  <router-outlet #route="outlet"></router-outlet>
  <wts-loading-anim></wts-loading-anim>
</div>

// WhizQuizModule & IdCheckModule do not have router outlets
```

Comment: Add your router-outlet code -

Comment: @Rahul OK, added the markup